# adb crashes when eclipse is started and my device is connected

Tags: android, adb

hi
I connect my device (rooted it already), run "adb devices" and I can see it.
Then I start eclipse - immidiately I get "adb.exe has stopped working" (and again every 10 seconds).
The device (desire HD) runs a 2.3 rom - Core V4.7. If I change to 2.2 based rom - cyanogen - it works.
Is that simply a bug with the core 4.7 rom? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I find the most simple solution to this annoying problem.

1. Just using Hboot to install the original driver for android.
2. Before you are doing the procedure, you have to reinstall the HTC Syn.

You have to follow these step in the right order.

[Soure](http://androidforums.com/incredible-all-things-root/173270-universal-windows-usb-drivers-adb-bootloader-disk-drive-htc-sync.html)

Answer (score 0):

Happens with me also,
When you have 2-3 AVDs or any Device connected to and you are trying to install any app on one or more AVDs or Devices then ADB crashes.
So do not use more than one AVD or devices if not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, but i found something on XDA : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1051798
Seems that we need to change a line on the default.prop at the / of the desire hd.
The problem is that I haven't found a way to do this (with adb push, it tell me "read-only file system", and i didn't find any root text editor).
Hope this will help, anyway.

Comment: There's an application called "root explorer" which claims to have a text editor, though I haven't used it personally.  Your phone would need to be rooted first though.

Comment: thanks NitroG42, but i've already tried this (using adb server push files). I think the problem is that I use a 2.3 rom and the drivers on my computer are for 2.2 HTC original rom.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the solution !
It was hard but it work :)
Go to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12141 , and vote for the issue btw !
Download the adb.exe fixed by oleg, and replace your adb with it.
If you try and adb crash, you should probably go to application/dev and uncheck/check usb debug, restart eclipse, and now i'm pretty sure it will work !

If you are on Linux (which i doubt because this issue seems to appear only on Windows), oleg provide the file to patch, so you just have to compile adb with it.

Comment: @reformy Did you still have your Desire HD ? Did you tried the solution posted on my link ?